# Adding Date as Optional Parameter with NULL Check Box in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, report, reportbuilder

I have report with date range as the parameters, User can narrow the results by selecting the date range. Now user want to make the date range fields  optional.  I enabled "Allow NUlls", user can gary out the date range parameters. The report is returning Zero records after selecting the Check BOX(Graying out the date fields)
I Follwed below ling to fix this, but while Im editing the Formula window, its either throwing END of formula expected ot Sysntax error over ':' .

I copied below code in the Edit as Formula window

OR(FIND(Fund_Project_Date, Parameter:Fund_Project_Date) <> 0, Parameter: Fund_Project_Date = EMPTY)

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/d2dd4521-fedd-4501-a675-1ec3b4b87989

Software used:
SSRS 2008 R2 , Report developed from Report Model edited through Report builder 3.0

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does the database query look like? Could you post your database SQL?

Comment: PaulStock, I'm developing report from Model deployed over report server. I was unable to put field as optional.

Comment: I found it . the solution is "=IIF(Isnothing(Parameters!ItemWorkflow_CUWC_Event_Date.Value),"12/12/1900",Para‌​meters!ItemWorkflow_CUWC_Event_Date.Value)" at Dataaset properties level not at Query Desiner Filter level. Thanks every one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it . the solution is "=IIF(Isnothing(Parameters!ItemWorkflow_CUWC_Event_Date.Value),"12/12/1900",Para‌​meters!ItemWorkflow_CUWC_Event_Date.Value)" at Dataset properties level not at Query Designer Filter level. Thanks every one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a ! not a :
Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry ,I got  "The Following Character is not valid: !"

Comment: I found it . the solution is "=IIF(Isnothing(Parameters!ItemWorkflow_CUWC_Event_Date.Value),"12/12/1900",Parameters!ItemWorkflow_CUWC_Event_Date.Value)" at Dataaset properties level not at Query Desiner Filter level. Thanks every one.